# Using embedded Jetty 9 with HTTPS only

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I am using embedded Jetty 9, where I want to allow https access, but no http.

I know I can easily configure a redirect in Jetty web.xml, but I don't have that file in the embedded version. I know I can use any file and point to it from the embedded version, but this should be easier.

So I searched and found this here http://blog.anvard.org/articles/2013/10/05/jetty-ssl-server.html where the author states "Of course, we could force the use of HTTP/S by just removing the HTTP connector."

So I did exactly this:

```
    Server server = new Server();

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(Keys.DOMAIN_CERTIFICATE_JKS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(Keys.DOMAIN_CERTIFICATE_KEY_MANAGER_PASSWORD);

    HttpConfiguration httpsConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
    SecureRequestCustomizer secureRequestCustomizer = new SecureRequestCustomizer();
    httpsConfiguration.addCustomizer(secureRequestCustomizer);

    ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConfiguration));
    serverConnector.setHost("192.168.0.5");
    serverConnector.setPort(9443);
    serverConnector.setIdleTimeout(15000);

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { serverConnector });
```

Problem: It doesn't seem to work. https is working fine, but when I access http, I get `200 OK` response with junk in the body (instead of the expected json response). So the server seems to process the request, but encrypt wrong, whatever. Or have I overlooked anything and my configuration is bad?

--

[image: http wireshark response]

Comment: When you say "I access http" does that mean you are using plaintext http over 9443?

Comment: Yes. I entered `http://...` into the browser and received something encrypted back. Is it normal when there is no redirect to the non-http port?

Comment: Was it `http://xxxxx:9443`? Because that would be totally expected to receive the encryption handshake or a notice that plaintext is not supported.

Comment: Yes, it was `http://xxxxx:9443`. I imagined it was the handshake that I received, but wanted to make sure. [@JohnnyV Thanks for answering and if you want post this as an answer so you get your points :) ]

Comment: Can you pastebin the entire request / response?  The fact that you got a 200 OK reply is odd since literally everything should be encrypted.  I want to double check before I have you thinking it is one thing or the other.

Comment: Here is what I could grab with Postman's chrome extension/interceptor but somehow it won't give me the raw request/response. I hope this is helpful: https://gist.github.com/oliverhausler/2690e2e2aff928eb0d37403bc99ecfdb [note that Github kicked out the non-printable characters, so I posted the url encoded http answer as well (or whatever that is)]

Comment: I was looking specifically for if the HTTP response contained a correct HTTP response header.  You can always use Fiddler or Wireshark to capture packets.

Comment: I think it does not. I attached a screenshot from wireshark above, and to me it looks like I only receive a few bytes. Is this capture helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you did everything correctly.  Connecting to the SSL port and sending regular HTTP (w/o the SSL handshaking) is returning an SSL Alert message.  Your HTTP client (for some reason) is giving you the `200 OK` message despite not even receiving an HTTP response.

What you are receiving is an SSL Alert message.

```
15 03 03 00 02 02 50 // response

15 = ALERT
03 03 = SSL version (TLS 1.x)
00 02 = Message Length
02 50 = Message
```