# How to force HTTPS with Jetty Embedded on Heroku with Automated Certificate Management

Tags: java, ssl, heroku, https, embedded-jetty

I have a REST app written in Java using Jetty Embedded, running on a Heroku environment. I would like to force all traffic to go through HTTPS. There are some good answers on how to achieve this such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362245/programatically-configure-ssl-for-jetty-9-embedded) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862650/using-embedded-jetty-9-with-https-only). However, all answers require the TLS/SSL certificate to be read from a file. I would like to use Heroku's Automated Certificate Management (details [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management)) to avoid having to renew certificates every year as they expire. Using ACM means that I do not have access to the certificate file.

Is there any way to configure Jetty to force HTTPS without reading the certificate from a file, or somehow to still be able to use Heroku ACM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll can do this with a servlet filter that implement `doFilter` like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)response;

    String protocol = req.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto");

    if (protocol.equals("http")) {
        String url = "https://" + req.getServerName() + req.getContextPath() + req.getServletPath();
        if (req.getPathInfo() != null) {
            url += req.getPathInfo();
        }

        System.out.println("Forwarding request to: " + url);
        resp.sendRedirect(url);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not forwarding protocol: " + protocol);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Here's [a complete example using Tomcat](https://github.com/kissaten/tomcat-disable-http/blob/master/src/main/java/ForwardHttpFilter.java), but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks @codefinger. When using Chrome, X-Forwarded-Proto is not included as a header, so this doesn't work for me. However, I see that HttpServletRequest.getScheme() seems to correctly identify whether I'm using HTTP or HTTPS, so I will try this approach and post the results.

Comment: Okay so after investigating it turns out that: HttpServletRequest.getScheme() is not reliable (it returns "http" even when using HTTPS on Heroku), and HttpServletRequest.isSecure() is also not reliable (returns false when using HTTPS on Heroku). The X-Forwarded-Proto header is not sent to servers running locally, but it is sent to servers running on Heroku. This answer is correct.

Comment: I believe the trouble w/ getScheme is because SSL termination happens at the Heroku router (thus the connection is HTTP at the Servlet). Best to check both?